# Using Volley without Gson

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit

Today I got to know that Retrofit uses gson(or any other convertor) to serialize or deserialize the json response (response that was got using okhttp or any related library).
Now, when I was naive(in some sense still am) and I used to use Volley and at that time I never used Gson or any related library and same for okhttp.But i used to get my response and inflate it successfully on my views.

**1. Now does Volley internally do what Retrofit does using Gson and Okhttp?**
If not? **2. Then how did i able to get values parsed without using anything?**

Below is the sample Codes that i used to write:-

```
  JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, URL_THUMB, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("server_response");
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=(JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
                    String id=jsonObject.getString("id");
                    String artist_name=jsonObject.getString("artist_name");
                    String img_id=jsonObject.getString("img_id");

                    listId.add(id);
                    listArtistName.add(artist_name);
                    listImgID.add(img_id);

                }

                recyclerView.setAdapter(comedy_adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }
    );
```

and now just inflate these list values to my views.

Where did I go wrong? (I don't think I was wrong as things went well and code always run fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you're parsing the response into JSON arrays and objects manually. Converters such as Gson let you parse the response into a variable of a custom object in a single line.

For example, if I have the following model:

```
public class Model {
    private int id;
    private String name; 
}
```

I can parse a string response using the following code:

```
Model model = gson.fromJson(str, Model.class);
```

Otherwise, you have to do it manually, like what you're doing at the moment:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("str");
int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
Model model = new Model(id, name);
```

In Retrofit 2 you don't even have to call `fromJson` - you simple receive the object you expect as an input parameter in `onResponse`. It's very useful when dealing with more complex models.