# How to make model class of complex jsonarray data using volley

Tags: android

Below I'm providing my code where I'm getting whole data from server but I'm unable to save data in model class due to multiple array. Kindly suggest me how can I do this using `Volley` + `JSON` not with `GSON`.

```
if (ResponseCode == 1) {

    JSONObject detailObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Detail");
    String firstName = detailObject.getString("FirstName");
    String lasttName = detailObject.getString("LastName");

    JSONArray ConstQuestionsArray = detailObject.getJSONArray("ConstQuestions");
    for (int i = 0; i < ConstQuestionsArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object1 = ConstQuestionsArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.e(TAG, "ConstQuestionsArray :: " + ConstQuestionsArray);

        String QuestionSetId = object1.getString("QuestionSetId");
        String PathwayId = object1.getString("PathwayId");
        String UserId = object1.getString("UserId");
        String RuleId = object1.getString("RuleId");

        JSONArray QuestionsArray = object1.getJSONArray("Questions");
        for (int j = 0; j < QuestionsArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject object2 = QuestionsArray.getJSONObject(j);

            String QuestionId = object2.getString("QuestionId");
            String QuestionName = object2.getString("QuestionName");
            Log.e("QuestionId", QuestionId);
            Log.e("question name", QuestionName);
            JSONArray choicelistArray = object2.getJSONArray("choicelist");
            for (int k = 0; k > choicelistArray.length(); k++) {

                JSONObject object3 = choicelistArray.getJSONObject(k);
                //Log.e(TAG, "choicelistArray :: " + choicelistArray);
                String choiceId = object3.getString("choiceId");
                String ChoiceName = object3.getString("ChoiceName");
                Log.e("choiceId", choiceId);
                Log.e("choice_name", ChoiceName);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your JSON response

Comment: here you can make... http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: {"Response": {"ResponseCode": 1,"ResponseText": "Success"}, "Detail": {"FirstName": "Raj","LastName": "Yadav","ConstQuestions": [{"QuestionSetId": 247,"PathwayId": 177,"UserId": 0,"RuleId": 0,"Questions": [{"QuestionId": 348,"QuestionName": "Do you have excessive daytime sleepiness", "choicelist": [ { "choiceId": 784,"ChoiceName": "Yes"},{"choiceId": 785,"ChoiceName": "No"}]},{"QuestionId": 349,"QuestionName": "Do you have craving for sweet foods?","choicelist": [{ "choiceId": 786,"ChoiceName": "Yes"},{"choiceId": 787,"ChoiceName": "No"}]},

Comment: {"QuestionId":0,"QuestionName":"Ca?","choicelist":[{"choiceId":8,"ChoiceName": "Y"},{"choiceId": 9,"ChoiceName":"No"}]}],"QuestionSet":null},{"QuestionSetId":7,"PathwayId": 180,"UserId":0,"RuleId":0,"Questions": [{"QuestionId": 8,"QuestionName":"Do","choicelist":[{"choiceId":4,"ChoiceName":"Y"},{"choiceId":5,"ChoiceName": "No"}]},{"QuestionId": 349,"QuestionName":"do?","choicelist": [{"choiceId":6,"ChoiceName":"Y"},{"choiceId":7,"ChoiceName":"No"}]},{"QuestionId":50,"QuestionName":"Canyo?","choicelist":[{"choiceId":8,"ChoiceName":"Y" },{"choiceId":9,"ChoiceName":"No"}]}],"QuestionSet":null}]}}

Comment: I have added response in two sections bcoz it was long @AD 10

Comment: follow this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053696/using-volley-without-gson

Comment: Kindly check my json response in this i have multiple list I want to save that .